# Custom file mapping python json to custom

Tags: python, json, parsing

I have recently created a parser in python 3 that converts files from a custom format (let's call the format .querty) into JSON (.json) for easier manipulation of its contents. Now I'm wondering what is the best way to translate back the JSON into my original format keeping all its original structure.

An example of the files can be seen below,

**example.qwerty**

```
Dict_abc_1{

    Dict_abc_2{
        HeaderGUID="";
        Version_TPI="999";
        EncryptionType="0";
    }

    Dict_abc_3{
        FamilyName="John Doe";
    }

    Dict_abc_4{
        Array_abc{
            {TimeStamp="2018-11-07 01:00:00"; otherinfo="";}
            {TimeStamp="2018-11-07 01:00:00"; otherinfo="";}
            {TimeStamp="2018-11-07 01:00:00"; otherinfo="";}
            {TimeStamp="2018-11-07 02:53:57"; otherinfo="";}
            {TimeStamp="2018-11-07 02:53:57"; otherinfo="";}
        }

        Dict_abc_5{
            LastContact="2018-11-08 01:00:00";
            BatteryStatus=99;
            BUStatus=PowerOn;
            LastCallTime="2018-11-08 01:12:46";
            LastSuccessPoll="2018-11-08 01:12:46";
            CallResult=Successful;
        }
    }
}
Code=999999;
```

**example.json**

```
{  
    "Dict_abc_1":{
        "Dict_abc_2":{
            "HeaderGUID":"",
            "Version_TPI":"999",
            "EncryptionType":"0"
        },

        "Dict_abc_3":{
            "FamilyName":"John Doe"
        },

        "Dict_abc_4":{
            "Array_abc":[
                {"TimeStamp":"2018-11-07 01:00:00", "otherinfo":""},
                {"TimeStamp":"2018-11-07 01:00:00", "otherinfo":""},
                {"TimeStamp":"2018-11-07 01:00:00", "otherinfo":""},
                {"TimeStamp":"2018-11-07 02:53:57", "otherinfo":""},
                {"TimeStamp":"2018-11-07 02:53:57", "otherinfo":""}
            ],

            "Dict_abc_5":{
                "LastContact":"2018-11-08 01:00:00",
                "BatteryStatus":99,
                "BUStatus":"PowerOn",
                "LastCallTime":"2018-11-08 01:12:46",
                "LastSuccessPoll":"2018-11-08 01:12:46",
                "CallResult":"Successful"
            }
        }
    },
    "Code":999999
}
```

**Structural definitions of .qwerty that are different to json**

- Dictionaries/Arrays don't have separates between them and their key
- Dictionaries/Arrays have two line breaks after the definition
- Variables use '=' as a separator between them and their value
- Variables use ';' after their value
- Arrays use {} instead of []

As my current .qwerty to .json parser uses lexical and syntactical analysis. I don't think it is necessary to recreate another parser using this method as the data is in a very manipulable form now (json). I was wondering if it would be a good idea to extend the json.dumps to adapt for my new definitions but don't know where to start or if it is possible.

I'm trying to do this an efficient manner, thoughts or approaches are much appreciated, Thank you.

Comment: Could you put in a link to your previous question, for cohesiveness? I remember seeing it myself but I don't remember what it was called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* this would work in a brute-forcey sort of way, though I haven't done any testing on it. One notable point of difficulty would be with lists, as this code snippet will not work if lists can contain anything besides dicts. You might have to adapt that part of the code - or if the contents of the dict inside the list doesn't have to be all on one line, you could make that run recursively as well. But regardless, hopefully this provides a good start for you to experiment with.

It's a recursive function. Three inputs: the dictionary to be parsed, a file to which to write, and the current level of indentation.

```
def print_qwerty(json_dict, file_descriptor, indent_level=0):
    for (k, v) in json_dict.items():
        if type(v) == dict:
            file_descriptor.write('    '*indent_level + k + '{\n')
            print_qwerty(v, file_descriptor, indent_level + 1)
            file_descriptor.write('    '*indent_level + ';}\n')
        elif type(v) == list:
            for i in v:
                args_str = ['{}="{}"'.format(k2,v2) for (k2, v2) in i.items()]
                file_descriptor.write('    '*indent_level + '{' + '; '.join(args_str) + '}\n')
        else:
             file_descriptor.write('    '*indent_level + '{}="{}";\n'.format(k, v))
```

Example usage:

```
import json
with open('example.json', 'r') as json_file:
    json_dict = json.loads(json_file.read())
with open('example.qwerty', 'w') as 'qwerty_file':
    print_qwerty(json_dict, qwerty_file)
```

Comment: There are issues but I think that's a really good idea! thanks, I'll update the post on completion for others

Answer (score 1):

Since your syntax looks relatively simple, you may be able to get away with not using lexical and syntactical analysis. Instead, you could use some regular expressions to recognize your arrays/dictionaries and variables, and just modify the formatting accordingly using simple replacement.

Comment: So use a defined list of replacements e.g. re.sub()'s like "(.*)": { to $1{\n to convert from json back ?

Comment: @AlexMika yes, it looks like that may be enough. While you could write a parser for it, that may be overkill if replacements will do it.